# Help with kernel of the linear map $F_A(B) = BA^t + AB^t$.

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, linear-transformations

I am stuck trying to figure out the kernel of this map.  Specifically $A$ is an 
orthogonal $n$ x $n$ matrix and $B$ is any $n$ x $n$ matrix.  If $A=I$ then the answer is clearly the antisymmetric matrices.  However for a non identity orthogonal matrix I'm kind of stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Work in the complex domain first, try $B$ of the form $u_i u_j^*$ where $A u_i =\lambda_i u_i$. This gives the eigenvalues of $F_A$.

Answer (score 3):

Calling $H=BA^T$ we see that it is skew-symmetric as
$$
H+H^T=BA^T+(BA^T)^T=BA^T+AB^T=0.
$$
Hence, for orthogonal $A$ we have $B=H(A^T)^{-1}=HA$, that is
$$
\ker F_A=\{HA\colon H\text{ is skew-symmetric}\}.
$$

Comment: Right! Just derived it myself.  Thanks!